# jquery pqgrid syntax error - missing semicolon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hate to post a question regarding syntax,  but this is driving me crazy.  I'm getting an error; missing semicolon.  It's pointing to obj.dataModel: {.

I'm just getting started with pqgrid, so take it easy.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        ListUsers=function(em){
            var emid = em.title;
            $('#userslistdiv').html('id-' + emid);
            $('#userslistdiv').show();
            //alert("it worked-" + emid);

        var obj = { width:700, height:400, title:"Grid From Array" };
        obj.colModel = [{ title: "IndivID", width: 100, dataType: "integer" },
            { title: "Lastname", width: 150, dataType: "string" },
            { title: "Firstname", width: 150, dataType: "float", align: "right" }];
        $("#userslistdiv").pqGrid(obj);
        obj.dataModel = [
            {dataType: "JSON"},
            {location: "remote"},
            {recIndx: "resourceid"},
            {url: "/cfc/basic.cfc?method=getIndivs&EmID=" + emid +"&queryFormat=column"},
            {getData: function (response) {
                return { data: response.DATA };
                }}];
        };

    });

</script>
```

Comment: `obj.dataModel:` should be `obj.dataModel = `

Comment: I edited the code.  Now I'm getting SyntaxError: missing } after property list.  I just don't see it.

Comment: Not seeing any errors in the (slightly-reformatted) version of the edited code, here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/PwzpzW.

Comment: I pasted your code and the errors went away.  AND, the grid popped up. Thank you both for taking on a question that so many others just ignore on principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've started using this tool not so long ago, but you could use syntax checkers like JSLint or JSHint, the latter being a less picky about formatting errors. Online version can be found [here](http://jshint.com/), and you can find plugins for many text editors and IDEs.

Pasting your original code indeed produces several `missing semicolon` errors, but the original error is the first found by the tool: `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`.